# Fields values reordering while implementing JsValue conversion with Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I try to implement some simple conversion to/from "JsValue" ( from play framework library) using "shapeless", as the beginning of my acquaintance with it. I know that such a thing is realized in a spray-json-shapeless library to work with sparay-json.
As I can see encoding goes well, but I got a problem with decoding.
This is my test:

```
"json de/serialization for N fields case class" should {
```

"work as expected" in {

```
   val nFields = NFields(1, 2.3, "test", true, 3)

   val jsValue = JsonEncoder[NFields].encode(nFields)

   val result = JsonDecoder[NFields].decode(jsValue)

   println(result.toString)

   result must equal(nFields)
```

}
}

After encoding object to `JsValue` I get the correct `JsObject` like this: `{JsObject@1686}{"f1":1,"f2":2.3,"f3":"test","f4":true,"f5":3}` but after decoding, the result object is `NFields(1,3.0,test,true,2)` so the value of field `“f2: Double” “2.3”` falls into place of field `“f5: Int” as “2”` and the value of field `“f5: Int” “3”` falls into place of field `“f2: Double” as “3.0”` and of course test fails with `“NFields(1,3.0,test,true,2) did not equal NFields(1,2.3,test,true,3)”`.

My Hlist decoder:

```
implicit def hlistDecoder[K <: Symbol, H, T <: HList](
       implicit
       key: Witness.Aux[K],
       hDecoder: Lazy[JsonDecoder[H]],
       tDecoder: JsonDecoder[T]): JsonDecoder[FieldType[K,H] :: T] =
       createInstance{
           case obj: JsObject =>
               val value= obj.value
               field[K](hDecoder.value.decode(value.head._2)) :: tDecoder.decode(JsObject(obj.value.tail))
       }
```

and Generic decoder:

```
implicit def genericDecoder[A, R](
   implicit
   gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
   dec: Lazy[JsonDecoder[R]]
): JsonDecoder[A] = createInstance(a => gen.from(dec.value.decode(a)))
```

Where is the problem? Any hints appreciated! Thanks in advance.